# Filtering User Logon events using Winlogbeat 5.x Processors

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat

I'm new to the Elastic stack and I'm now working with Winlogbeat to monitor user logons. Prior to sending the events to Elasticsearch, I want to drop logon events that were not generated by users (e.g. system and service accounts).

I tried to use the `processors`, but it doesn't seem to be working. The documentation is really minimal and there is no working example.

This is my processor configuration:

```
processors:
- drop_event:
    when:
        regexp:
            event_data.TargetUserName: ".*$"

processors:
- drop_event:
    when:
        equals:
            event_data.LogonType: "0"

processors:
- drop_event:
    when:
        equals:
            event_data.LogonType: "5"
```

However I get this as the result:

```
"LogonType": "3",
"ProcessId": "0x0",
"ProcessName": "-",
"SubjectDomainName": "-",
"SubjectLogonId": "0x0",
"SubjectUserName": "-",
"SubjectUserSid": "S-1-0-0",
"TargetDomainName": "DOMAIN",
"TargetLogonId": "0x14d570eec",
"TargetUserName": "MACHINE-01$",
"TargetUserSid": "S-1-5-18",
"TransmittedServices": "-"
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my processor config?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by, "I want to filter logon events that were not coming from user before they were sent to Elasticsearch."

Comment: I think I figured out what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared three separate `processors` variables in your YAML configuration file. There should only be one. `processors` is a list so you can add multiple items to the list. There is [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/winlogbeat/current/configuration-processors.html#conditions) of the processors and their conditions.

```
processors:
 - <processor_name>:
     when:
        <condition>
          <parameters>
 - <processor_name>:
     when:
        <condition>
          <parameters>
```

Given that you want to drop the event when any of the conditions are true you could use a single `drop_event` processor with an `or` condition. Here's an example.

```
processors:
- drop_event:
    when.or:
      # This filters logons from managed service accounts.
      # The trailing dollar sign is reserved for managed service accounts.
      - regexp.event_data.TargetUserName: '.*\$'

      # This filters logon type 0 which is used for system accounts.
      - equals.event_data.LogonType: '0'

      # This filters logon type 5 which is used for service accounts.
      - equals.event_data.LogonType: '5'

      # This filters anonymous logons which are typically benign.
      # Anonymous users have extremely limited privileges.
      - equals.event_data.TargetUserName: 'ANONYMOUS LOGON'
```

I thought you might be following some of the conditions listed in this Winlogbeat blog post - [Monitoring Windows Logons with Winlogbeat](https://www.elastic.co/blog/monitoring-windows-logons-with-winlogbeat).

Comment: So that's the problem, I will try it now. Thank you.